# List-text wont change color via Javascript button

Tags: javascript

So, it´s my first post and here is my problem, but first, let me say that i tried 2-3 solutions from here, but they just wont work... i think something didnt fit right, but i dont know what.

i have a small list and i want to change the color if i press a button.
I only get it working if i use an inline onclick-function! but only for one text.

I want to change the color of the "Sonnenfarben" lists (rot,orange,gelb) to black when i click the button.

Heres my code

```js
document.getElementById(button).onclick = click();
  
     function click()  {      
     document.getElementById('one').style.color = 'black'
     }
```

```html
<button 
     id="button" 
     onclick="document.getElementById('one').style.color = 'black'">Nightmode
     </button>
    
    <h2>Farben</h2>
      <ol class="ordered-colors">
        <li>blau</li>
        <li>pink
  
    <h2>Sonnenfarben</h2>
      <ul id="night" class="unordered-colors">
        <li id="one">rot</li>
        <li id="two">orange</li>
        <li id="three">gelb</li>
      </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li>braun</li>
        <li>grau</li>
      </ol>
```

So far i tried to use "getElementByClassName and TagName" with no result, i always get an error message that something dont fits. Also, if i copy my onclick code into my javascript it wont work anymore. Another try was to use "allQuerySelector?" to get all three id´s at once, but it didnt worked.

im working in codepen for this.

can someone help me please?

greetings

Comment: Your inline onclick is fine. It works as expected, though it is changing the color from the default (black) to black, which makes it look like nothing happens. Your JS is fine, however your `getElementById(button)` should be `getElementById("button")`, and again, it changes it from default (black) to black.

Comment: If you are wanting to change the style of multiple elements via a dark mode, I would definitely recommend doing this with classes, rather than trying to update each element's style directly. This could be done either as a single class on the whole body `body.darkmode` with updated relevant CSS for each element underneath, or by applying `.darkmode` to each element which needs to be updated, with the relevant rules in CSS. I recommend the former.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that the text i want to change is colored "red,orange and yellow" and i want to change it to black. 
but i only get it to change only the the red one to black, even if i use "getbyClassName"

Comment: Gotcha. Well your `<li>` elements don't have a class. They only have IDs defined, so they can't be targeted by `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should look like this. This iterates over all the li elements.

```
document.getElementById(button).onclick = click();
  
function click()  {   
  var list = document.querySelector(".unordered-colors");
  list.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(item) {
     item.style.color = "black";
  });
}
```

Comment: ok, so this realy works! thank you! all lists are colored black, the only thing im struggling with is that the text gets changed instantly, without clicking the button.

Comment: I would suggest that you equate the onclick to the function. like:

`document.getElementById(button).onclick = function(){
   var list......
}`

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you start by using an IDE that highlights syntax errors and warns on potential errors. If you are a student, JetBrains will let you use their software for free. If not (or in any case) Microsoft Visual Studio Code may be a good choice.

I say that because right off the bat, I notice errors that an IDE would have flagged for you. You would likely be warned that you have passed an undefined variable named "button" into your first getElementByID() use, rather than a string "button" that matches the element. You also have an unterminated line (not harming anything, but inconsistent).

Also, though technically within spec, your code appears to clearly not be doing what you intend it to do, due to a misplaced end of line item tag.

As issues often cascade from one to another, you should always make sure your basic syntax is correct before trying to figure out what is wrong with an algorithm. An IDE will be a great help in this.

Comment: hm yeah, i just startet with a few only courses until im starting as real student and worked with Studio Code as well, but for this, i was told to do it in codepen ^^.

i think im going to rebuild it in studio code and if it works transfering it to codepen